# Unable to download an image via urlretrieve() function

Tags: python, urlretrieve

I am on Ubuntu 16.10. I am trying to download an image using `urlretrieve()` function of python. I am getting the following errors.

```
File "downloadImage.py", line 9, in <module>
    downloadWebImage("https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-601accaf841bba9145d3c46bece1ea10-p")
  File "downloadImage.py", line 7, in downloadWebImage
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, fullName)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
    return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 245, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 443, in open_https
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1053, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 897, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 859, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1278, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 353, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 601, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 830, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
IOError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```

Also my code is :

```
import random
import urllib

def downloadWebImage(url):
    name = random.randrange(1,1000)
    fullName = str(name) + '.jpg'
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, fullName)

downloadWebImage("https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-601accaf841bba9145d3c46bece1ea10-p")
```

So what are the errors, why are they occuring? What is their fix?

Comment: Can't reproduce the Error in python2.7

Comment: Works for me, too (python 2.7.13).

Comment: Can you get the image via a browser? It seems like you don't have a needed cipher suite installed.